# No longer possible to include Carbon headers during GCC compile on Yosemite?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, macos-carbon

Before upgrading my OS and XCode for Yosemite, I used to be able to include the Carbon header from a c++ file when compiling with gcc without error:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Now, on Yosemite, this compiles with `clang++` but fails with `g++` (4.7 installed via macports):

```
In file included from /usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:51:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20,
                 from ./test.cpp.cpp:39:
/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:143:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:143:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:362:3: error: 'dispatch_block_t' has not been declared
```

Is it no longer possible to include Carbon headers when compiling with GCC?

Answer (score 1):

I think Carbon is 32 bits only, and your GCC does it in 64 bit natively, try with -m32

Comment: hum maybe are you compiling your code c++ 11, could you try -std=c++03 ?